# Crystal 2008 section export group selection

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working in **SAP BO Crystal 2008** with data tables from an **ERP system**.

Here is what I have.  The table contains General Ledger journals, detail entries.  Grouped by Journal number showing General Ledger account number, year, month and value.  Each journal sums to 0 as it includes debit and credit entries.

This is what I am trying to select:

All journals which contain a specific GL Code.  I need all journal entries for other GL codes as long as the specific code I am looking for (7000-00) is included in the journal.

This is an extract of the data:

```
378     GL Code Journal value       in/exclude

2015    1   7000-00 378 855.15          include

2015    1   7200-00 378 -855.15         include


2015    1   3200-00 379 -41.06          exclude

2015    1   3210-00 379 -0.47           exclude

2015    1   3220-00 379 -26.51          exclude

2015    1   7200-00 379             exclude
380                     
2015    1   7000-00 380 866.75          include

2015    1   7200-00 380 -866.75         include

2015    1   3200-00 381 -2.88           exclude

2015    1   3210-00 381 -0.27           exclude

2015    1   3220-00 381 -1.84           exclude

2015    1   7200-00 381 4.99            exclude
```

As you can see I have made the Group Header Journal number show if the journal group contains `7000-00` but how can I supress the data for any journals that do not contain `7000-00`?

i.e. I want to see data from Journal 378 bit not 379. I want to see 380 but not 381 etc.

Any help would be appreciated.  I think this needs a formula in section expert but am at a loss of how to do it.

Thanks
Guys

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a group using `Journal` and place all your fileds that you wish to see in detail section.
2. now create a below formula `@count` and place it at the end of the detail section.

   ```
   if (Code =7000-00)
   then 1
   else 0
   ```

Take the sum of count in group footer using insert summary.

Now for supress condition of group header, details and group footer

```
if (sum({@count},{Journel}))>0
then false
else true
```

Change the formula as per your report.

Comment: Thanks Siva,  I understand where you are going with this up to the supress bit.  In the Section Expert in GH I put your last formula in (adjusted for my fields)  if (sum({@@COUNT},{GenJournalDetail.Journal}))>0
then false
else true.  It does not however eliminate journals that do not contain 7000-00.  Do I put this formula in the GH or GF section against the surpress.  I think its just me being thick.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you both so much.  It works brilliantly and is so simple.  I just had to get my head round the fact that this formula had to go in Header, Detail and Footer group selection as a surpress formula.